# Omit previously imported articles by comparing existing articles aliases with generated aliases

Tags: articles, database, alias, cli

I am needing to compare the generated articles aliases of items imported from an external news API against those that are already stored in the `com_content` database to ensure that duplicates are ignored and only new articles are created.

The code is being executed in the `cli` directory using the following functioning code. Imported news items are successfully stored as articles, but duplicate aliases causes the script to abort.

I have placed an if conditional at the bottom of the `insertArticles` function, but this code is not working. Either the placement or the implementation of the code is incorrect.

```
public function doExecute(): void {
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query
    ->select(array('a.title', 'a.alias'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid') . " = " . $db->quote('8'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadObjectList();

  // Fetch the JSON data and Run the insertArticle bulk data import to articles function
  $curlOpts = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.dtn.com/publishing/news/articles?categoryId=16%2C17%2C18&limit=2&maxAge=30&apikey=placeholder',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  ];
  try {
    $fetchedArticles = $this->curlToObject($curlOpts);
    if ($fetchedArticles) {
      $this->out(JText::_('Fetched Articles: ' . count($fetchedArticles)));
    }
    $insertedIds = $this->insertArticles($fetchedArticles);
    if ($insertedIds) {
      $this->out(JText::_('Inserted IDs: ' . implode(', ', $insertedIds)));
    }
  } catch (exception $e) {
    $this->out(JText::_($e->getMessage()));
  }
}

private function curlToObject(array $curlOpts): array {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $error = curl_error($ch); // Get the last error
  curl_close($ch);
  if ($error) {
    throw new Exception($error);
  }
  return json_decode($result);
}

private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {
  require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php';
  $articleModel = new ContentModelArticle([]);

  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $articleData = [
      'id' => 0,
      'catid' => 8,
      'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
      'alias' => JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title),
      'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary),
      'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content),
      'state' => 1,
      'access' => 2,
      'created_by' => 332,
      'language' => $article->language,
      'rules' => [
        'core.edit.delete' => [],
        'core.edit.edit' => [],
        'core.edit.state' => []
      ],
    ];

    if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
      throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
    } else {
      // If $result->alias matches $article->alias, skip saving of that article to prevent duplicate alias error
      foreach($results as $result) {
        if ($result['alias'] != JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title)) {
          $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $newIds ?? [];
}
```

Comment: Please pay careful attention to method scope. `$results` is not declared inside of `insertArticles()` before you try to loop on it.  I recommend using a professional IDEA (such as PHPStorm) to help you to be aware of simple mistakes like these.  Your query will need to be moved out of `doExecute()` and into `insertArticles()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for the suggestions. I am learning and improving my back end programming skills as I go.

Comment: Paying for PHPStorm was a major milestone in my development career.  I wish someone would have introduced me to it years sooner.

Comment: @mickmackusa I will download a trial of the app and give it a go. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for marking this page as resolved by awarding the green tick.  I would like to say additionally: please get into the habit of upvoting correct answers that are "helpful" to you.  I am not saying this to mooch for rep points for self-gain -- I have no need for rep points as a moderator.  However, in the interest of growing this community and helping other users to unlock privileges, it is beneficial for users to upvote answers which are "good", educational, helpful, and show best practices. Little actions like these go a long way to incentivising better posting in the community.

Comment: In the same vein, please also upvote questions which are clear, complete, and unique -- especially if they spared you from having to ask the same question.  When users realise that making great contributions is appreciated and almost guarantees rep increases, more people will come forward and post questions and answers more often.  Making JSE feel "more welcoming" in this way is just one of the primary advantages of post in JSE instead of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to move your query into your `insertArticles()` method scope so that `$results` is available as well as move your filtration before the `save()` call is executed.

I will propose creating a separate private method for this filtration to keep the processes responsibilities separated.  Making a single trip to the database will help with performance as well as generating a lookup array.  A lookup array leverages array keys to check for existence and this is always the most performant way of checking in PHP.

```
private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {
    require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php';
    $articleModel = new ContentModelArticle([]);

    foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article) {
# filter here^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $articleData = [
            'id' => 0,
            'catid' => 8,
            'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
            'alias' => JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title),
            'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary),
            'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content),
            'state' => 1,
            'access' => 2,
            'created_by' => 332,
            'language' => $article->language,
            'rules' => [
                'core.edit.delete' => [],
                'core.edit.edit' => [],
                'core.edit.state' => []
            ],
        ];

        if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
            throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
        } else {
            $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
        }
    }
    return $newIds ?? [];
}

private function removeDuplicateAliases(array $articles): array
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select('a.alias')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid') . " = " . $db->quote('8'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $aliasLookup = array_flip($db->loadColumn());

    foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
        if (isset($aliasLookup[JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title)])) {
            unset($articles[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $articles;
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it worked as expected. I really appreciate your assistance with this functionality I am working on for this client.